# Firebase auth doesn't retain the login details in firebase web

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have created a web app in firebase using JavaScript. It has multiple web pages and on each page, I print **current User uid** on the console just to check whether it is working correctly or not. Whenever I register user with Email & Password authentication, It is correctly stored in Firebase Authentication as well as user details are getting stored in Firebase Database. The login window shows current user uid on console. But as soon as I **Reload** the login page it prints **current user uid is `Null`** in the console. on other webpages, It shows **previously logged-in user's uid**. I have added **`onAuthStateChanged`** code on each webpage to check current user uid still it is not retaining Correct Current User uid.

The code that I have tried:

```
<script>
// <!-- Check Current user login -->

// Register the callback to be fired every time auth state changes

var ref=firebase.auth();
ref.onAuthStateChanged(function(authData) {
if (authData) {
  console.log("User " + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid + " is logged in ");
} else {
  console.log("User is logged out");
}
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should get the user id from the returned authData object

```
<script>
// <!-- Check Current user login -->

// Register the callback to be fired every time auth state changes

var ref=firebase.auth();
ref.onAuthStateChanged(function(authData) {
if (authData) {
  console.log("User " + authData.uid + " is logged in ");
} else {
  console.log("User is logged out");
}
});

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you Anas it is working correctly now. But it is throwing error on currentUser is null when I try to display currentUser. Code snippet: var uid=firebse.auth.currentUser.uid; console.log(uid);

Comment: I think it is because your trying to access currentUser while firebase is still initializing. However, with "onAuthStateChanged" you get a callback for when everything is ready. Also authData should have the same data as firebse.auth.currentUser

Comment: Yes exactly firebase.auth.currentuser should have same data as authdata. There is again one issue. When I logout from one page it should reflect the logout event on other pages also. (yes I have authData on each page) but instead it shows user is logged in on other pages. Why it doesn't reflect this logout event on other pages on the same firebase web application. How to achieve the uniform authentication on all the webpages?! :/